# Count number of instances of a character and use it in a condition

Tags: awk, replace, conditional-statements

I have a csv file (t.txt) in which some lines have 7 commas and some have 8
If the line has 8 commas, I want to remove the 2nd comma in that line.

Any suggestions? I have been trying

```
if [[awk -F "," '{print NF-1}' == 8]]; then sed 's/\,//2'; t.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to add sample of Input and expected output along with your efforts in your post in CODE TAGS `{}` button, you could do so now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided samples of Input_file or expected output so couldn't test, could you please try following.

```
echo "a,a,a,d,f,g,h,h,f" |
awk '
 match($0,/,[^,]*/){
   print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
   next
}
1'

a,aa,d,f,g,h,h,f
```

In case you want to check 8 commas condition too then replace `match` with `match($0,/,[^,]*/)  && NF==9` to above code too.

Comment: @Chinmay Kalluraya, give it sometime after your question and then try to select any answer out of all answers as correct one to close the thread fully.